# Had you had asked

Tags: grammar, american-english, word-usage

Let's say in this scenario:

Someone asked me for help to do certain thing.  I gave a negative response.  That person then asked for the reason.  I responded with:

"Had you had asked me nicely ...."

What I meant to say was "If you had/have asked me nicely ..."

Question:  Does the former have the same meaning as the later?

Edit:  Just to make sure there are not any differences:  My response was a statement, not a question to that person.

Comment: You must say: "Had you asked me nicely ...", *without the second *had*. It has the same meaning as "If you had asked me nicely ...". In Present-day English this inversion is only permitted with past-form auxiliaries and modals, and in practice is largely restricted to *had*, *were* and *should*.

Comment: @StoneyB: great explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Had you had asked me nicely ...."

is incorrect. It should be EITHER:

> If you had asked me nicely...

OR

> Had you asked me nicely...

which both mean the same thing.